# plotly bar chart with multiple index

Tags: pandas, plotly, multi-index

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I'm looking how can I plot a stacked plotly bar chart from a multi-index pandas dataframe.
My dataframe looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr3bS.png). And the full dataset in csv format is here:

```
Type;Cam;Ref;Date;Number;Last_time
Categorie 23 IMC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 2;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 2;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 2;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 2;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 6;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 2;XV450;Apr-01-2023;6;01/04/2023 17:19
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 8;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 8;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 4;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;7;01/04/2023 19:58
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 23 IMC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 35 MC;Camera 4;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 23 IMC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 7;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;8;01/04/2023 22:37
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;9;01/04/2023 23:04
Categorie 12 IMC;Camera 6;XV450;Apr-01-2023;9;01/04/2023 23:04
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 3;XV450;Apr-01-2023;9;01/04/2023 23:04
Categorie 20 EC;Camera 6;XV450;Apr-01-2023;9;01/04/2023 23:04
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 2;XV450;Apr-01-2023;9;01/04/2023 23:04
Categorie 0.51 IC;Camera 1;XV450;Apr-01-2023;9;01/04/2023 23:04
```

For each Date & Number (6,7 ...) from index, I want to plot the count value in Y axis in a stacked bar chart with "Type" column values (Categorie 20 EC, Categorie 0.51, ...)

Example: For the date "Apr-01-2023", the first bar chart refers to the number 6. This bar chart has a stacked bar with these "Type" : Categorie 0.51 IC, Categorie 12 IMC, Categorie 20 EC,Categorie 23 IMC.
The total value in Y axis shloud be: 9+2+1+1 = 13.
And the X axis should be:"Apr-01-2023 Number 6".

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

DATA = pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv", sep =";", encoding = 'utf-8')
DATA = DATA.reset_index(drop = True)
DATA['count'] = 1
DATA = DATA.groupby(["Date", "Number", "Type"]).sum()
DATA.head(5)
```

I want **to reproduce this example of plotly bar chart** here :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnmJ5.png)

Thank you for any help,

Edit 1 : I have tested the solution of @**Serge de Gosson de Varennes**
[image]
But, now if I'm adding a new trace on the figure, the order is not respected... This is very weird.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=pivot_df["Number"], y=(pivot_df["count"].astype(float)).ewm(alpha = 0.75).mean().shift(1),
    name='Forecasting',
    mode = 'markers+lines',
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
df['count'] = 1
df = df.groupby(["Date", "Number", "Type"]).sum()

data = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index=["Date", "Number"], columns="Type", values="count", fill_value=0)

fig = px.bar(data, x=data.index.get_level_values(1), y=data.columns, title="Stacked Bar Chart",
             labels={"value": "Count", "variable": "Type", "Number": "Number (x-axis)"},
             color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

which gives you

[image]

I fi you want to add a trace:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
df['count'] = 1
df = df.groupby(["Date", "Number", "Type"]).sum()

data = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index=["Date", "Number"], columns="Type", values="count", fill_value=0)

fig = px.bar(data, x=data.index.get_level_values(1), y=data.columns, title="Stacked Bar Chart",
             labels={"value": "Count", "variable": "Type", "Number": "Number (x-axis)"},
             color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')

number_trace = go.Scatter(x=data.index.get_level_values(1), y=data.index.get_level_values(1),
                          mode='lines+markers', name="Number", marker=dict(size=10, color="#F9A71F"))

fig.add_trace(number_trace)

fig.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Serge de Gosson de Varennes, I have edited the main topic, I'm now facing to an other trouble when I'm adding a new traces on figure.

Comment: @notafk Updated my answer. Just for your information. It is not apprecited by most people when changing the scope of a question aafter having gotten answers. ;-)

Comment: Many thanks, I understand, my apologies. In Y axis, I'm looking to get the sum value of each bart in order to draw the forecasting line.
Y = data["count_max_per_bar"].ewm(alpha = 0.75).mean().shift(1)

Answer (score 0):

full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# read csv
DATA = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";", encoding="utf-8")

# pivot table to get counts
pivot_df = DATA.pivot_table(
    index=["Date", "Number", "Type"], aggfunc="size"
).reset_index(name="count")

# visualise as stacked barplot
fig = px.bar(pivot_df, x="Number", y="count", color="Type", barmode="stack")
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="Number",
    yaxis_title="Count",
)
fig.update_xaxes(
    tickformat=".0f",
    tickvals=pivot_df["Number"],
    ticktext=pivot_df["Date"] + " Number " + pivot_df["Number"].astype(str),
)
fig.show()
```

stacked barplot:
[image: Stacked barplot]

`pivot_df` pivot table:

```
    Date        Number  Type                count
0   Apr-01-2023 6       Categorie 0.51 IC   9
1   Apr-01-2023 6       Categorie 12 IMC    2
2   Apr-01-2023 6       Categorie 20 EC     1
3   Apr-01-2023 6       Categorie 23 IMC    1
4   Apr-01-2023 7       Categorie 0.51 IC   10
5   Apr-01-2023 7       Categorie 12 IMC    4
6   Apr-01-2023 7       Categorie 20 EC     3
7   Apr-01-2023 8       Categorie 0.51 IC   6
8   Apr-01-2023 8       Categorie 12 IMC    1
9   Apr-01-2023 8       Categorie 20 EC     3
10  Apr-01-2023 8       Categorie 23 IMC    2
11  Apr-01-2023 8       Categorie 35 MC     1
12  Apr-01-2023 9       Categorie 0.51 IC   4
13  Apr-01-2023 9       Categorie 12 IMC    1
14  Apr-01-2023 9       Categorie 20 EC     1
```

Comment: Thank you @hlin03, If I add a new traces on figure, the order will be respected ? Please see the bottom of the main topic, I have edited the topic.